# Partition dataset by timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of millions of rows like so, with no duplicate time-ID stamps:

```
ID | Time | Activity 
a  |   1  | Bar 
a  |   3  | Bathroom 
a  |   2  | Bar 
a  |   4  | Bathroom 
a  |   5  | Outside
a  |   6  | Bar 
a  |   7  | Bar
```

What's the most efficient way to convert it to this format?

```
ID | StartTime | EndTime | Location 
a  |   1       |    2    |  Bar 
a  |   3       |    4    | Bathroom
a  |   5       |   N/A   | Outside
a  |   6       |   7     | Bar
```

I have to do this with a lot of data, so wondering how to speed up this process as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `groupby`

```
df.groupby(['ID','Activity']).Time.apply(list).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0:'starttime',1:'endtime'}).reset_index()
Out[251]: 
  ID  Activity  starttime  endtime
0  a       Bar        1.0      2.0
1  a  Bathroom        3.0      4.0
2  a   Outside        5.0      NaN
```

Or using `pivot_table`

```
df.assign(I=df.groupby(['ID','Activity']).cumcount()).pivot_table(index=['ID','Activity'],columns='I',values='Time')
Out[258]: 
I              0    1
ID Activity          
a  Bar       1.0  2.0
   Bathroom  3.0  4.0
   Outside   5.0  NaN
```

Update

```
df.assign(I=df.groupby(['ID','Activity']).cumcount()//2).groupby(['ID','Activity','I']).Time.apply(list).apply(pd.Series).rename(columns={0:'starttime',1:'endtime'}).reset_index()
Out[282]: 
  ID  Activity  I  starttime  endtime
0  a       Bar  0        1.0      2.0
1  a       Bar  1        6.0      7.0
2  a  Bathroom  0        3.0      4.0
3  a   Outside  0        5.0      NaN
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for responding. This works, but I edited my question to clarify. An activity can reappear again later and needs to appear as a distinct grouping if it was interrupted by a previous activity.

Comment: @NBC is this what you need ? If it is , would you consider accept and up-vote